# Is it possible to call user display name into firebase messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know is it possible to get the user names from the firebase authentication and use it in composing the fcm notifications so I can great the users with their names.

In firebase auth all the email templete like email verify templete, password reset templete has a  code `%DISPLAY_NAME%` and this will add the user name to that email. I tried the same in fcm title but no luck.

If there's a no direct approach what are the possible hacks to achieve it.

Any suggestions are appreciated..!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such mail-merge like functionality in the Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

If you want each user to see a personalized message, you have a few options:

1. Send a separate message to each user. To optimize this, you can [use the batch API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages) to send messages in groups.
2. Send an invisible, [data-only message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) to all users, and then handle the display of the (personalized) notification in your application code

Comment: Your second approach looks easy I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestion.